# Identify a futurology book from the 1980s with sci-fi style depictions about how the future will look

Tags: story-identification

I read this book between 1985 and 1990, it was in English and it had a hardback red cover.

It covered several depictions of the future, and was sparsely illustrated with humorous single-panel cartoons or drawings.

Some of the content I remember includes:

- the standard depiction that we will consume all our necessary calories, vitamins and minerals through a single pill a day, with meals being unnecessary
- a humorous cartoon that covered the fact that wars would not be something that the average person was involved in or even knew happened - it showed two people talking to each other, one saying "did you know there was a war last night?" and the other replying "Oh?  Who won?"
- a segment on future air travel, which would involve massive airliners holding thousands of people, which never landed in normal operation.  They would travel on routes around the world, with smaller short range aircraft landing on their backs to transfer travellers to and from ground destinations.  These airliners would have cinemas, shopping malls and other things not associated with air travel.  The massive airliners would land on massive runways in the Sahara desert for maintenance.